# Environment variables in nodejs deployed app

Tags: node.js, azure, environment-variables

I am developing a Node application in which I am connecting to an azure database. I would like to keep the credentials as environment variables. I have a .env file and I have the credentials in that. When I run the app locally I can fetch the credentials from the file but when it is deployed in Azure, the process.env.SERVER is returning undefined and so I am unable to connect to the server.

Answer (score 2):

In Azure Web Apps, we can define these environment variables in section **Application settings** -> **App settings** by using [Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com):

[image]

Then these variables can be accessed from our Node.js code via `process.env["variablename"]`.

Comment: ..or `process.env.variablename`. Case sensitive.